# Google Calendar API in Ruby using Service Account

Tags: google-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to access the Google Calendar API in Ruby using a Service Account (e.g., server-to-server communication).

I'm having difficulty finding a good tutorial/example of how to do this. I have created a service account, and downloaded a JSON private key file. How can I authenticated with the Calendar API using this JSON file and make a request for calendar information?

The [Ruby API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/ruby/) examples don't contain examples for apps that aren't running on a Google Apps domain.

To summarize, I'm looking for some help to understand how to

1. Authenticating with the API using the [API Ruby
   Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) using the
   JSON private key file for my service account
2. Make some requests to get calendar information after I've
   authenticated

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50377730/148844