# Google Calendar API: "You need to have writer access to this calendar."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I'm using the Google Calendar API in my Rails 5.2.3 app and trying to create events on a Google Calendar within my G Suite domain. I'm already able to read the calendar and list events. When I try to insert an event, I get the error "requiredAccessLevel: You need to have writer access to this calendar."

As this is for an internal application, I have registered a service account in the Google API console and have verified that the account is able to read calendars and events.

In the G Suite Admin Console, I've given the service account permissions for the scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events

I created the calendar itself under my account and have added the service account with "Make changes to events" permissions

This is a sample of the code I'm running.

```rb
    calendar_id = '12345' #obviously not but I've verified that I have the right calendar.
    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
    authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
    client = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    client.authorization = authorization

    start_time = Time.current
    end_time = Time.current + 2.hours

    newEvent = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new({
        summary: "Sample Event",
        start: {
            date_time: start_time.rfc3339,
            time_zone: start_time.strftime("%Z")
        },
        end: {
            date_time: end_time.rfc3339
            time_zone: end_time.strftime("%Z")
        }
    })

    result = client.insert_event(calendar_id, newEvent)
```

I'm sure I've missed a permission somewhere for write access, but haven't figured out why I get "requiredAccessLevel: You need to have writer access to this calendar." instead of the insert working. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50376820/how-do-i-authorize-a-service-account-for-google-calendar-api-in-ruby/50377730#50377730. Possible duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, @Chloe. That fixed it. I had searched but apparently not long enough.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Chloe in the comment above. The solution was to change the first 5 lines to to

```rb
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)

auth_client = authorization.dup
auth_client.sub = 'account@mydomain.com'
auth_client.fetch_access_token!

client = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
client.authorization = auth_client
```