# Erro to connect Google Sheets API

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-sheets-api, service-accounts, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to follow these Ruby quickstart code(https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby#step_2_set_up_the_sample),

```
require "google/apis/sheets_v4"
require "googleauth"
require "googleauth/stores/file_token_store"
require "fileutils"

OOB_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob".freeze
APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Sheets API Ruby Quickstart".freeze
CREDENTIALS_PATH = "credentials.json".freeze
# The file token.yaml stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
TOKEN_PATH = "token.yaml".freeze
SCOPE = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::AUTH_SPREADSHEETS_READONLY

##
# Ensure valid credentials, either by restoring from the saved credentials
# files or intitiating an OAuth2 authorization. If authorization is required,
# the user's default browser will be launched to approve the request.
#
# @return [Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials] OAuth2 credentials
def authorize
  client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file CREDENTIALS_PATH
  token_store = Google::Auth::Stores::FileTokenStore.new file: TOKEN_PATH
  authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new client_id, SCOPE, token_store
  user_id = "default"
  credentials = authorizer.get_credentials user_id
  if credentials.nil?
    url = authorizer.get_authorization_url base_url: OOB_URI
    puts "Open the following URL in the browser and enter the " \
         "resulting code after authorization:\n" + url
    code = gets
    credentials = authorizer.get_and_store_credentials_from_code(
      user_id: user_id, code: code, base_url: OOB_URI
    )
  end
  credentials
end

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

# Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
# https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
spreadsheet_id = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"
range = "Class Data!A2:E"
response = service.get_spreadsheet_values spreadsheet_id, range
puts "Name, Major:"
puts "No data found." if response.values.empty?
response.values.each do |row|
  # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
  puts "#{row[0]}, #{row[4]}"
end
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from quickstart.rb:42:in `<main>'
    4: from quickstart.rb:22:in `authorize'
    3: from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/googleauth-1.1.2/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:67:in `from_file'
    2: from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/googleauth-1.1.2/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:67:in `open'
    1: from /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/googleauth-1.1.2/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:70:in `block in from_file'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/googleauth-1.1.2/lib/googleauth/client_id.rb:84:in `from_hash': Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present. (RuntimeError)
```

I think it's a authentication issue.

I'm using a service accounts authentication https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#create_credentials_for_a_service_account

Maybe the code doesn't work for service account authentication, but I couldn't find any documentation that talks about how to integrate Google Sheets with my code using service account authentication.

Comment: Can you share the part in your code in which you are performing the authorization for the service account? Also, what credentials are you using for this app - are the ones created for the service account?

Comment: I created the json like this:

`Open the Google Cloud Console.
At the top-left, click Menu menu > IAM & Admin > Service Accounts.
Select your service account.
Click Keys > Add keys > Create new key.
Select JSON, then click Create.`

Comment: And how are you adding these credentials for your code, can you share the snipped for this as well?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I'm gonna say that your credentials configuration did not setup properly.

I'm gonna follow these steps if I were you:

Step 1: Install this gem

https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby

Step 2: Get your Google Service Account Credentials, when this step is done, you should get a `.json` file. I'm gonna call it `google_service_account_credentials.json` file.

Step 3: Try this snippet:

```rb
require "google/apis/sheets_v4"
require "googleauth"

CREDENTIALS_PATH = "google_service_account_credentials_path/google_service_account_credentials.json"
SCOPE = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::AUTH_SPREADSHEETS_READONLY

# Author & Authen with Google by Google Service Account Credentials
authorizer = Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials.make_creds(
  json_key_io: File.open(CREDENTIALS_PATH),
  scope: SCOPE)

authorizer.fetch_access_token!

# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::SheetsV4::SheetsService.new
service.authorization = authorize

# Some demo code to prove it run
# Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
# https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
spreadsheet_id = "1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms"
range = "Class Data!A2:E"
response = service.get_spreadsheet_values spreadsheet_id, range
puts "Name, Major:"
puts "No data found." if response.values.empty?
response.values.each do |row|
  # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
  puts "#{row[0]}, #{row[4]}"
end
```

Step 4: Enjoy (hope it helps) <3

Further information you can get from here, I just customize the answer so it suit your need :"))
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56747012/6542152

Comment: You need to explain further for your answer instead of pasting links only

Comment: @NickVu thank you, this is my first answer so far, gonna edit it now :")

Comment: @RickyNguyen I think that there is a typo on `service.authorization = authorize`. It should be `service.authorization = authorizer`. Otherwise, thank you very much for your answer. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using from the [Ruby quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/ruby#step_2_set_up_the_sample)   Is designed to for use with a `Authorization credentials for a desktop application`

This code can be used with either an installed client or a web client created on google cloud console.  Which is what the error message is telling you

> Expected top level property 'installed' or 'web' to be present.

The code for use with a service account is not the same

Links: [Oauth service](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client/blob/main/docs/oauth-server.md)

Comment: this code returned me: `Can't convert Google::Auth::ServiceAccountCredentials into String or Array. (TypeError)` using the service account authentication json.

I don't think Oauth is the best choice as I just need to dynamically create sheets.

Comment: I think you should check the documentation on the page i linked.  I have been unable to find any better source for a sample with service accounts.

Comment: theres a few more examples here you may want to look around https://stackoverflow.com/q/50376820/1841839